# How to copy the script from a ".as" file into the main timeline of flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have a program made in flash who runs well, the actions on the .fla file are empty, it has a class who makes all the the work:

[image]

This is the content of the class:

```
package {

    import flash.events.Event;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.parsers.DAE;

    [SWF(width=640, height=480, backgroundColor=0xCCCCCC, frameRate=30)]

    public class Earth extends PV3DARApp {

        private var _earth:DAE;

        public function Earth() {
            addEventListener(Event.INIT, _onInit);
            init('Data/camera_para.dat', 'Data/flarlogo.pat');
        }

        private function _onInit(e:Event):void {
            _earth = new DAE();
            _earth.load('model/minecraft.DAE');
            //_earth.addEventListener(Event.OPEN,imageLoaded);
            _earth.scale = 1.5;
            _earth.rotationX = 90;
            _markerNode.addChild(_earth);

            //addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _update);
        }

        private function imageLoaded(e:Event):void { trace("HOLA"); }

        private function _update(e:Event):void {
            _earth.rotationZ -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

I want to pass all the script from the class to the acctions on the main timeline, i mean, i dont want to use the class, but i have no idea how to do this, eliminating the "private" string in all the functions and eliminating some other logical  thinks like "package {" and others is not enough.

So please, how can i code the same program using only the actions tab from flash? Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to even do this? I would highly recommend against it!

Comment: Amen to that. Normally you want to to exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to agree with the idea that using timeline code is a *bad idea*.

Now, going to your code, it's hard to know for sure without knowing what the parent class does.

I'm assuming that your are using the FLARToolKit example code. I would do as @Adam Harte shows you in his answer, plus modify the PV3DARApp class so that you accommodate things a bit.

Since the whole idea is a bad one in my book, I won't bother to make things in a proper way, just suggest quick changes.

In PV3DARApp, make _markerNode public:

```
//protected var _markerNode:FLARBaseNode;
public var _markerNode:FLARBaseNode;
```

In PV3DARApp and ARAppBase, change the method init from protected to public:

```
public function init(cameraFile:String, codeFile:String, canvasWidth:int = 320, canvasHeight:int = 240, codeWidth:int = 80):void {
```

Then, it should go something like this:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import org.papervision3d.objects.parsers.DAE;

var _earth:DAE;
var _holder:PV3DARApp  = new PV3DARApp;

function _onInit(e:Event):void {
    _earth = new DAE();
    _earth.load('model/minecraft.DAE');
    //_earth.addEventListener(Event.OPEN,imageLoaded);
    _earth.scale = 1.5;
    _earth.rotationX = 90;
   _holder. init('Data/camera_para.dat', 'Data/flarlogo.pat');
    //_markerNode.addChild(_earth);     
  _holder._markerNode.addChild(_earth); 
    //addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _update);
}

function imageLoaded(e:Event):void { trace("HOLA"); }

function _update(e:Event):void {
    _earth.rotationZ -= 1;
}

addEventListener(Event.INIT, _onInit);
init('Data/camera_para.dat', 'Data/flarlogo.pat');
```

Comment: hello @goliatone, it seems that you know alot about flarttoolkit, im very new at this, and the reason i wanted to migrate the code from the class to the timeline is that i want to make a preloader for the .dae load and some other thinks that i have no idea how to make them on the class, if you can help me this i will be very hapy :), thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a good idea. I (and most other AS3 developers) think all timeline code should be destroyed, but it should go something like this:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import org.papervision3d.objects.parsers.DAE;

var _earth:DAE;

function _onInit(e:Event):void {
    _earth = new DAE();
    _earth.load('model/minecraft.DAE');
    //_earth.addEventListener(Event.OPEN,imageLoaded);
    _earth.scale = 1.5;
    _earth.rotationX = 90;
    _markerNode.addChild(_earth);

    //addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _update);
}

function imageLoaded(e:Event):void { trace("HOLA"); }

function _update(e:Event):void {
    _earth.rotationZ -= 1;
}

addEventListener(Event.INIT, _onInit);
init('Data/camera_para.dat', 'Data/flarlogo.pat');
```

There is no reason to not just use the document class. I would suggest learning how classes work. There are a bunch of great resources out there including:

- [Kirupa.com - Classes in ActionScript3](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/classes_as3_pg1.htm)
- [gotoandlearn](http://gotoandlearn.com/)

Comment: IMHO timeline code should be avoided at all cost, save for the odd stop() or play()... it just makes things overly complicated, especially when trying to leverage OO design concurrantly. Study up! you'll be glad you did.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the destruction of timeline coding.  MovieClip makes me cringe.  now that Adobe has Flash Catalyst, it would be nice to see them completely replace the timeline in Flash Professional with a proper layers panel for library assets.

Comment: @Adam Harte: It seems that it would be more complicated than that. The main class extends another class (PV3DARApp) which obviously is not being used in your example code.

Comment: @goliatone ah, good spotting. Didn't see that. Will edit my answer